# Change Dateformat in a Column from dd.mm.yyyy to yyyy-mm-dd in SQL

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a column with Dates like '12.05.2021' and I want to transform the Dates to following format:
2021-05-12. But I dont know how to do it.

Comment: what's the data type ?

Comment: [No attempt](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/). [No code](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nocode/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i assume it's in string ,so :

```
SELECT TO_VARCHAR(TO_DATE('12.05.2021' ,'MM.DD.YYYY'),'YYYY-MM-DD');
```